# Xml file not getting uploaded fully

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest

In my C#/winforms app, using System.Net's HttpWebRequest class, I programmatically upload an xml file to a server(ABC) outside of our company network.
(App user is located in NY and server is located in UK).

We've not been having any issues with this in last 2 years until yesterday when we found out that the file received by the server is not complete making the xml not well-formed and invalid.

I save the xml on our local server before sending it to ABC.
We notice that the size(36 kb) of the this xml is same what was received by ABC but almost half of the xml received by them is empty with lots of blank spaces and some tags appear broken.

Not sure why this could have happened and how to programmatically resolve this going forward.
Would anyone be able to advise on this please?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you flush the xml writer when saving it to disk locally?  Did you flush the Upload code sending it to the server?

Most stream objects have a Flush method on them.  Not calling it can work fine sometimes, but other times you won't get the whole thing on the other end, just a piece of it.

Comment: I've gotten burned by the using statement and web uploads. The using statement will close and dispose your stream before the writing gets done.